# Java ComboBox will not get populated

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have tried everything to figure out why my combobox will not get populated but nothing works.

In my FXML file I have.

```
<ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" layoutX="162.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="334.0" promptText="Select past popular pizza" />
```

In my controller I have the following

```
public class ServeController {
public ObservableList<String> pizzas1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML public ComboBox<String> comboBox;
private void initialize() {
comboBox.getItems().addAll(
        "jacob.smith@example.com",
        "isabella.johnson@example.com",
        "ethan.williams@example.com",
        "emma.jones@example.com",
        "michael.brown@example.com"  
    );
}
```

I have even tried with

```
public ObservableList<String> pizzas1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1","2","3","4");
```

to try to get some kind of data to show up but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Do you specify your controller in your FXML (via the fx:controller attribute)?

Comment: Yes I do, like so <GridPane alignment="center" gridLinesVisible="false" hgap="0" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="controller.ServeController">

Comment: Add `@FXML` before  `private void initialize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are initalizing controller in "standard" way. I'm guesing that `private void initialize()` method is never invoked. Your `ServeController` does not implement `Initializable` interface. Correct code should look as following:

```
public class ServeController implements Initializable {

    public ObservableList<String> pizzas1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "jacob.smith@example.com",
                "isabella.johnson@example.com",
                "ethan.williams@example.com",
                "emma.jones@example.com",
                "michael.brown@example.com"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing `Initializable` is NOT necessary. The only issue is that any members with a visibility other than `public` are not visible to the `FXMLLoader`, unless they are annotated with `@FXML`. ([See c0der's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44364430/2991525))

Answer (score 2):

I assume that if you add a printout to `initialize()` you'll see that it is not invoked.
To get `initialize()` invoked you need to annotate it: `@FXML private void initialize()`